# Blazor Parent/Child components code problem

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0

I am new to Blazor and came up to an issue which I am unable to fix. I have created 2 custom components - one for a table and one for pagination. I am using this approach since there will be a design and I want to reuse them in my Blazor app. When I click on the next button for going to next page nothing happens. These are my components and their @code related in separate classes:

Table component:

```
@typeparam TItem
<div>
    <table class="table">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var (columnNumber, displayName) in GetPropertyInfoForHeaderColumn())
                {
                    <th>@displayName</th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                <tr>
                    @foreach (var (columnNumber, propertyValue) in GetPropertyInfoForItem(item))
                    {
                        <td>@propertyValue</td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <Pagination CurrentPage="CurrentPage" TotalPages="TotalPages" OnCurrentPageValueChanged="HandlePageChange"></Pagination>
</div>
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using SFA.AdminTool.BlazorUI.Shared.Common.Attributes;

namespace SFA.AdminTool.BlazorUI.Client.Components.Common;

public partial class AdminToolTable<TItem>
{
    [Parameter]
    public int PageSize { get; set; } = 10;

    [Parameter]
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; } = 1;

    [Parameter]
    public int TotalPages { get; set; } = 1;

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment TableHeader { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<TItem>? AdminToolTableRow { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public IReadOnlyList<TItem>? Items { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> OnCurrentPageValueChanged { get; set; }


    private List<(int columnNumber, string displayName)> GetPropertyInfoForHeaderColumn()
    {
        var properties = typeof(TItem).GetProperties();
        return properties
        .Select(prop =>
        {
            var columnAttribute = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AdmintoolTableHeaderColumn), true)
                                            .OfType<AdmintoolTableHeaderColumn>()
                                            .FirstOrDefault();

            var columnNumber = columnAttribute?.ColumnNumber ?? 0;
            var displayName = columnAttribute?.DisplayName ?? prop.Name;

            return (columnNumber, displayName);
        }).OrderBy(v => v.columnNumber).ToList();
    }

    private List<(int columnNumber, string propertyValue)> GetPropertyInfoForItem(TItem item)
    {
        var properties = typeof(TItem).GetProperties();

        return properties.Select(prop =>
        {
            var rowAttribute = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AdmintoolTableRowColumn), true)
                                            .OfType<AdmintoolTableRowColumn>()
                                            .FirstOrDefault();

            var columnNumber = rowAttribute?.ColumnNumber ?? 0;
            var propertyValue = prop.GetValue(item)?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
            return (columnNumber, propertyValue);
        }).OrderBy(v => v.columnNumber).ToList();
    }

    private async Task HandlePageChange(int newPage)
    {
        this.CurrentPage = newPage;
        await OnCurrentPageValueChanged.InvokeAsync(this.CurrentPage);
    }
}
```

Pagination Component:

```cs
<div class="pagination">
    <button disabled="@IsFirstPage" @onclick="GoToPreviousPage">Previous</button>
    <span>Page @CurrentPage of @TotalPages</span>
    <button disabled="@IsLastPage" @onclick="GoToNextPage">Next</button>
</div>

@code {

    private bool IsFirstPage => CurrentPage == 1;

    private bool IsLastPage => this.CurrentPage == this.TotalPages;

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> OnCurrentPageValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; } = 1;

    [Parameter]
    public int TotalPages { get; set; } = 1;

    private async Task GoToPreviousPage()
    {
        if (!this.IsFirstPage)
        {
            this.CurrentPage--;
            await OnCurrentPageValueChanged.InvokeAsync(this.CurrentPage);
        }
    }

    private async Task GoToNextPage()
    {
        if (!this.IsLastPage)
        {
            CurrentPage++;
            await OnCurrentPageValueChanged.InvokeAsync(this.CurrentPage);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my usage of table component:

```
@page "/nplProducts"

@if (NplProducts.Count > 0)
{
    <AdminToolTable 
        Items="NplProducts" 
        CurrentPage="CurrentPage"
        PageSize="PageSize"
        TotalPages="TotalPages">
    </AdminToolTable>
}
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using SFA.AdminTool.BlazorUI.Infrastructure.Contracts.Services.Common.Http;
using SFA.AdminTool.BlazorUI.Shared.Models.ApiRequestObjects.ImageRecognition.NplProducts;
using SFA.AdminTool.BlazorUI.Shared.Models.ViewModels.ImageRecognition.NplProducts;
using System.Net.Http.Json;

namespace SFA.AdminTool.BlazorUI.Client.Pages.ImageRecognition.NplProducts
{
    public partial class Index
    {
        public List<NplProductVM> NplProducts { get; set; } = new();

        [Inject]
        public HttpClient HttpClient { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; } = 1;

        [Parameter]
        public int PageSize { get; set; } = 1;

        [Parameter]
        public int TotalPages { get; set; } = 1;


        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            var result = await GetData(this.CurrentPage, this.PageSize);

            this.NplProducts = result.Data;
            this.CurrentPage = result.CurrentPage;
            this.PageSize = result.PageSize;
            this.TotalPages = result.TotalPages;
        }

        private async Task<PaginatedResponse<List<NplProductVM>>> GetData(int currentPage, int pageSize)
        {
            var request = new NplProductsRequestPaginated(currentPage, pageSize);
            var response = await this.HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"https://localhost:7109/api/imageRecognition/nplProducts/GetNplProducts?request", request);
            var data = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<PaginatedResponse<List<NplProductVM>>>();

            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Please advise me what is the problem with my code so when I click on Next button to send a request to the API which will return me the items related for the page which I am trying to access

Answer (score 0):

The only piece that seems to be missing from glancing at your code is the subscription to OnCurrentPageValueChanged in your page. It would have to look  something like this:

```
@if (NplProducts.Count > 0)
{
    <AdminToolTable 
        Items="NplProducts" 
        CurrentPage="CurrentPage"
        PageSize="PageSize"
        OnCurrentPageValueChanged="HandlePageChange"
        TotalPages="TotalPages">
    </AdminToolTable>
}
```

And one more method to handle it in your Index class - something like:

```
protected override async Task HandlePageChange(int currentPage)
{
    this.CurrentPage = result.CurrentPage;
    
    var result = await GetData(this.CurrentPage, this.PageSize);

    this.NplProducts = result.Data;
    this.TotalPages = result.TotalPages;
}
```